# How does SonarQube calculate coverage through JaCoCo?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

JaCoCo just outputs jacococ.exec which is the input for Sonar. In that file, there seems to be only the info:

```
- Class name
- Total Class Probes
- Executed Class Probes
```

But then, SonarQube cannot rely solely on these values as it needs to tell you which are the exact lines unconvered, so Sonar is performing an analysis on itself. So how does it use Jacoco report? And why does it need it?

Comment: SonarQube is using the combination of the Source code and the coverage output file. Both has to be in sync. See also [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Unit+Tests+and+Coverage+Results+Import)

Comment: But then why does it need the jacoco file if it is gonna analyze the source code by itself at method/line level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jacoco ignoring Lombok code, is this expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149531/jacoco-ignoring-lombok-code-is-this-expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So how does it use Jacoco report? And why does it need it?

SonarQube itself alone doesn't / can't know anything about which tests you actually executed and how they cover your code. To obtain this information it relies on third-party test coverage tools. In case of Java it relies on data collected and provided by JaCoCo as [explained in answer on similar question from you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149531/jacoco-ignoring-lombok-code-is-this-expected) (JaCoCo collects execution information in `exec` file, and obtains line numbers and other information from `class` files during generation of report), or SonarQube can rely on data in ["generic format"](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/).

Comment: Hi Godin! Thanks for your kind answer. I think I understood the root of my misunderstanding. Checking the jacoco.exec file in Eclipse (and open it as binary as well) looked like only contained info on classes + counts on probes, but no info on line level. But this info must be there, as they told me the whole binary is the source for all the jacoco reports. So now I see all info is there and Sonar can absolute rely on jacoco.exec for all the coverage info

Comment: Is it expected in the near future that Sonar uses Jacoco reporting instead of exec (I read several sources explaining that should be the case)?

Comment: Into SonarQube you already can import XML file, which JaCoCo Ant Tasks or JaCoCo Maven Plugin produce - see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-jacoco Import of `exec` file is going to deprecated very soon - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1651