# JaCoCo ignoring Lombok code, is this expected?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I am using Lombok 1.18.2 and JaCoCo 0.8.3, which theoretically recognize/ignore lombok annotations. I did a test, added the `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true` param in my `lombok.config` and then I see the generated annotation on my target classes decompiled code.

But I am surprised to open jacoco.exec file and see that things like @Getter  increase the "Total Probes" values, but keep untouched the "Executed Probes" one. 
Is this expected?

If so, how can SonarQube make smart use of it, if by pointing it to the jacoco.exec files, there is only information on total/hit probes? How can Sonar tell one of this probes has something to do with lombok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using Lombok 1.18.2 and JaCoCo 0.8.3, which theoretically recognize/ignore lombok annotations.

Not theoretically, but [practically](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/513#issuecomment-291170668).

Not "ignore lombok annotations", but methods annotated with [`@lombok.Generated`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Generated.html), or even more precise quoting entry from 0.8.3 [changelog](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html):

> Classes and methods annotated by annotation whose retention policy is runtime or class and whose simple name contains "Generated" (previously equality was required) are filtered out during generation of report

---

> But I am surprised to open jacoco.exec file and see that things like @Getter increase the "Total Probes" values, but keep untouched the "Executed Probes" one. Is this expected?

Yes, this is expected. Filtering of methods doesn't happen during instrumentation of classes (insertion of probes). `exec` file is not final report, it contains raw information about all probes inserted in class. Filtering of methods happens during generation of report (analysis of `exec` and `class` files), i.e. during execution of [`report` JaCoCo Ant Task](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) for example.

> If so, how can SonarQube make smart use of it, if by pointing it to the jacoco.exec files, there is only information on total/hit probes? How can Sonar tell one of this probes has something to do with lombok?

SonarQube [embeds JaCoCo as a library](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.11.0.17289/pom.xml#L90) and [use it to analyze `exec` and class files for generation of their report](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/5.11.0.17289/java-jacoco/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/jacoco/JacocoReportReader.java#L31-L38).

And that's why JaCoCo release announcements usually contain following statement, e.g. for [0.8.2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/aMi1SkcfLZc/_UWgrC9xAQAJ):

> As before - please note
>
> 0.8.2 version of integrations developed as part of JaCoCo project by us (Ant Tasks, Maven Plugin and Command Line Interface) provide Java 11 support and new filters,
>
> tools that directly read exec files (which is not a final report) and embed JaCoCo as a library for generation of report will provide ability to analyze Java 11 class files and to use new filters only after they updated to this version of JaCoCo.
>   So please follow/wait/etc respective vendors such as
>
> SonarQube - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2876 , or try to use new plugin that reads XML report - https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-jacoco

Comment: Hi again! Sorry if both questions are so similar, one was about Jacoco+Sonar, and this is focused on lombok. So considering what you exposed, and provided Sonar uses jacoco.exec intermediate file instead of its reports, I understand that @@lombok.Generated parsing is done from Sonar own source analysis and not from interpreting jacoco exec, right?

Comment: I mean, since Sonar does not use Jacoco reports but the binary (and this does not filter anythin), then Jacoco does not intervene at all on the lombok exclusion right? Then how does sonar do, it reads the annotation from the class and excludes it by default in the same way as jacoco reporting does?

Comment: No, you completely misunderstood what I wrote - please re-read including the provided links. Things are exactly opposite - SonarQube doesn't intervene into analysis of `exec` file that is done by JaCoCo library embedded into SonarQube. And [very first link](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/pull/513#issuecomment-291170668) shows that `Generated` annotation is handled by JaCoCo.

Comment: @You are right, sorry, I meant Sonar as in Sonar's jacoco, in contrast with maven's jacoco producer. I guess my confusion is the following: when you set a class exclusion in jacoco, this information is not visible in the exec but in the presence/absence of reports (i.e at reporting), so we need to refilter at sonar level.  But when it comes to lombok filtering, looks like this info is contained in the jacoco.exec, so when sonar uses its internal jacoco to parse the binary it is identifying that his should not be accounted. That is why it is confusing. Am I finally certain? Sorry for bothering