# Sonarqube and Jacoco Gradle Plugins

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm using

https://docs.gradle.org/4.2.1/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

and

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube/2.6.2

In a java app.

Running './gradlew build jacocoTestreport sonarqube' works fine, I can see my code coverage in sonarqube.

My question is how though?

I don't declare the sonar.jacoco.reportPaths, so that defaults to build/jacoco/test.exec, which is created by the jacocoTestReport task.

So does sonarqube run that exec or something? Or does that jacoco.exec know where the xml reports have been created at build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml?

Or, is that XML path some other sort of default that sonarqube is using?

It's all working, so great, but I'm documenting it all for others and a bit confused as to how it all hangs together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does SonarQube calculate coverage through JaCoCo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149460/how-does-sonarqube-calculate-coverage-through-jacoco)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SonarQube plugin for Gradle will find the path looking at the Jacoco task context and then automatically set the sonar.jacoco.reportPaths property.